# Jquery simple infinite loop slider logic

Tags: jquery, slider, logic, infinite-scroll, jquery-ui-slider

I'm new to Jquery and making a simple static slider with five images of same class name (.sl_thumb)
This is code on Next and Previous Anchor --
Right Anchor (.right_nav_link), Left Anchor (.left_nav_link)
Main Div of slide(.slide_container)

My previous and Next Links are working fine but when slider reaches to last slide it stops, I am trying to make infinite looping slider, so that it should again reach to first slide after last. As a beginner, I've tried many things but confused, what can be the best possible logic I can use.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var src = 'img/img1.jpg';
    $(".right_nav_link").click(function () {
        var next = false;
        $($("img").filter(".sl_thumb")).each(function (key, value) {
            if ($(this).attr('src') == src) {
                next = true;
            } else if (next) {
                next = false;
                src = $(this).attr('src');
                $(".slide_container").css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
                return;
            }
        });
    });
$(".left_nav_link").click(function () {
        var prev = false;
        $($("img").filter(".sl_thumb").get().reverse()).each(function (key, value) {
            // console.log(key,value);
            if ($(this).attr('src') == src) {   
                prev = true;
            } else if (prev) {
                prev = false;
                src = $(this).attr('src');
                $(".slide_container").css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your logic would be much simplier if you changed it to put a class on the active element (like 'active') and then when you click next or previous, it's easy logic to find the next or previous image and make it active, rotating back to the beginning/end when you reach either side.

Comment: However, as it is, the issue is that your logic sets next/prev to true, but it's the last iteration, so the else doesn't happen.  If you want to keep this logic, you need some other variable to check if you actually changed the image.  If you didn't change it after the loop, you'd then do the "reset" logic back to the other end

Comment: Sir, How can I reset the each() after it completes, I thought like this but cant implement it. I wanted that I should check if each(value) reaches to the last I should reset the each() . Is that possible?. Sorry for anything foolish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var src = 'img/img1.jpg';
  
  function adjustSlideContainer ( adjustPositionAmount ) {
    //get all the images
    var $thumbnails = $( 'img.sl_thumb' );
    //find the current one shown
    var $current = $thumbnails.filter( '[src="'+ src +'"]' );
    //get its index
    var currentIndex = $thumbnails.index( $current );
    //adjust the index to the image that should be shown next
    var nextIndex = currentIndex + adjustPositionAmount;
    
    if ( nextIndex < 0 ) {
      //if it's before the first one, wrap to the last one
      nextIndex = $thumbnails.length - 1;
    } else if ( nextIndex >= $thumbnails.length ) {
      //if it's after the end one, wrap to the first one
      nextIndex = 0;
    }
    
    src = $thumbnails.eq( nextIndex ).attr( 'src' );
    $( '.slide_container' ).css( 'background-image', 'url(' + src + ')' );
  }
  
  $(".right_nav_link").click(function() {
    //go to the next image
    adjustSlideContainer( 1 );
  });
  
  $(".left_nav_link").click(function() {
    //go to the previous image
    adjustSlideContainer( -1 );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, @Taplar, This is working fine and probably the proper way to do it. I need to code more and more to develop these logics by my own. Thanks again, Belated Merry Christmas!

Comment: @user9437856 not all snippets have to be runnable.  In this case the comments should be enough to explain what it is doing.  Given the OP accepted the answer, this was enough to solve their issue.